# Makefile runs but does not clean object files and executable file

Tags: c, shell, makefile

My makefile runs but it does not execute the cleaning of the object file and executable files, as specified by `rm -f $(PROJECT) $(OBJ)`. What am I doing wrong?

**makefile**

```
PROJECT = cfind
HEADERS = $(cfind.h)
OBJ = argv.o globals.o main.o pathInfo.o

C99 = cc -std=c99
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -Werror

$(PROJECT) : $(OBJ)
    $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROJECT) $(OBJ)

%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f $(PROJECT) $(OBJ)
```

Comment: What command are you using to run the makefile? If it's not `make clean`, why should it make that target?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I never knew that. I was just using the `make` command. My apologies - this is my first time using the makefile. Thank you for the help.

Comment: One of the primary objectives of the `make` system is to run only what needs to be run to make the targets specified.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Out of curiosity, then why does it automatically run `$(PROJECT) : $(OBJ)` and `%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)`, without the same requirement to explicitly specify them?

Comment: What target did you tell it to make? It makes whatever target you tell it to make. If you don't specify a target, the first one in the makefile is used.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I just used the `make` command - nothing else. Is this the incorrect way to handle things?

Comment: It's correct if you want to make the default target. If you want `clean` to be part of the default target, add it by changing `$(PROJECT) : $(OBJ)` to `$(PROJECT) : clean $(OBJ)`. But that would be pretty silly -- why make it dependent on files it's going to remove anyway? Why do you want it to rebuild the project even if nothing has changed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So by using the code specified above with only the `make` command, the target `%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c $<` is actually ignored, too?

Comment: No, that target is used because it's a dependency of the first target. The first target has `$(OBJ)` as a dependency. Say `argv.o` doesn't exist. Then `make` will know it needs to make that in order to make the default target, so it will look for the rule for that, and match the `%.o` rule. The `$(OBJ)` says you can't make that target without first ensuring everything in `$(OBJ)` is up-to-date.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This makes sense! My understanding of makefiles is significantly improved now. Thank you very much. Please leave these comments so that I may reference them again in the future, if necessary. I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `make`, it makes whatever target you tell it to make. Unless you tell it make the `clean` target, or that target is a dependency of the one you did tell it to make, it won't make that target. The main purpose of makefiles and specifying dependencies (rather than just using a build script) is to perform only the required operations. By default, `make` makes the first target in the makefile.

I think you are missing the whole point of a makefile and the reason you specify dependencies. The reason you have `$(PROJECT) : $(OBJ)` is so that it knows it doesn't have to make that target if the object files haven't changed.

Why do you want it to rebuild the project even if nothing has changed?